# Error retrieving LDAP info with search

Tags: java, ldap

I am trying to setup an LDAP LoginModule (using [BrowserLdapLoginModule](http://www.boxerboxes.ca/JBoss_Ldap.shtml)). The user/password is correctly; it retrieves the roles from the user but when it tries to extract the CN value it cannot find the values.

I have followed the process, and in the end the failure is that I get a javax.naming.NameNotFoundException in the following line

```
NamingEnumeration roleAnswer = ctx.search(searchBaseDN, roleFilter, roleconstraints);
```

with the following values (doble quotes not included):

- searchBaseDN(String) = "OU=Roles,DC=siafake,DC=aplssib"
- roleFilter(String) = "(distinguishedName=CN=Urgencias,OU=Roles,DC=siafake,DC=aplssib)"
- derefRoleAttribute(String[] = { "cn" };

With that data, I expect the search to return me `Urgencias`, yet I only get the exception. It is not a permissions issue, since with the same user/password I can browse the LDAP tree without problem.

Any idea / suggestion? Thanks in advance.

[image: LDAP capture]

Comment: Use `cn=urgencias` as the filter.

Comment: the question is that `cn=urgencias` (in fact, `urgencias` alone) is the result. The code gets `CN=Urgencias,OU=Roles,DC=siafake,DC=aplssib` by obtaining the roles (`memberOf`) the user that is logging in. This step tries to isolate the CN token of the value.
I know I could just parse it, but I am trying hard to just use the module "as is" because it is used in other servers in our parent company, and I want to avoid creating a version of it that only works in my servers/apps (thereby increasing future problems).

Comment: OK. I am not sure I undersrtand. The `cn` attribute is requested as part of the search. All the values of `cn` are returned when the search returns. The entry uses one value of `cn` as a component of the distinguished name, but there is no need to parse anything, since the values of `cn` are returned in the search response.

Comment: @TerryGardner it looks like I did a couple of invalid assumptions (check my answer). Thanks for your efforts, I am going to upvote you in a couple of places as a thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here is the answer that I found (also, some clarifications to the comments from Terry Gardner comments)

My sysadmins gave me user A ("system" user, that can connect and browse the LDAP). The user that will connect to my application would b user F (final user). When asked about samples to configure my jboss, they redirected my to the BrowserLdapModuleLogin (BLML).

Turns out, BLML works by doing an initial connection with user A, for retrieving user F data (full LDAP "name").

After that, a new connection is setup using user F connection data to validate user/password and retrieve the groups (`memberOf` attribute) to which it belongs. Until this point, all works as it should (at least with our setup).

The trouble began when I did setup the option to just get the "CN" value (instead of `CN=value,OU=organization....`). By setting up this option, the module tries again to login **as user F** into the roles tree to get the attribute. But it happens that F does not have permissions to do so.

As the module was provided by our IT people and I am new to LDAP, I assumed I was just setting up something wrong, and I did not want to change anything in the code. In the end, it happens that in the system that uses it, this module was used only for authentication; the roles were extracted from another DB and I have been forced to code around this issue.

Sorry for the annoyances...